# Is there an online service (or software) that emulates the iPad browser?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I have a website that isn't working on the iPad and was hoping to find a version of the iPad browser that runs stand-alone and is able to pull open something analogous to the developer tab in firefox/chrome, so that I can see what specifically is going on and where it's failing.

The site works fine in computer browsers, and unfortunately without being able to see a console, I'm really at a loss as to what's failing on the mobile device, so, I see other answers here in SO that point to emulators, but they all seem to be simply display emulators without any additional debugging resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own a Mac or you're willing to run OS X in a virtual environment, [the free Xcode 4](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) 
can simulate an iPad. As to the developer tab, you can turn on the [Web Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) in the simulator by going into Settings -> Safari -> Advanced.

Comment: No problem, I hope it works out for you. I've actually never used Web Inspector on the simulator, so if that doesn't work, there's also [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome, available on the Chrome web store is an addon called User-Agent Switcher, a little widget that sits next to your address bar and allows you to change you user agent, making the server show that you are, say, an iPad, causing the server to respond with the correct web-page.

I am not sure if this could help you, but is a nice tool for Web-Developers :)

You can at that point also use Chrome's nice inspector tool :p

[This is the one I use, however there are many others available.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf?hl=en-US)